# How to make a post build script for buildout

Tags: python, build, build-automation

I'm using zc.buildout for my project.  How do I execute a post-build script -- meaning, after buildout runs, fetches all the eggs and puts everything in place -- now I want it to run a script.  Specifically, I want it to run my unit test runner which is a script called bin/test

Answer (score 1):

You can specify several `parts` in `[buildout]` section, one of your parts can run test scripts (e.g. using [`pbp.recipe.noserunner`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pbp.recipe.noserunner/), [`zc.recipe.testrunner`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.recipe.testrunner/), ...)

Comment: Not sure why this wasn't marked as answer already, this is THE answer to the asker's question.